# Python - Espaços aparecem do nada ao imprimir resultados no print()

Tags: python, string

Estou com um problema com a minha função, sou bem iniciante em python então não entendo muito da linguagem, então me desculpem se é um erro bem amador.
Quando vou imprimir na tela o resultado através do print() a primeira linha sai normal, mas todo início da segunda em diante aparece com um espaço no começo. Exemplo:

```
Jose Ganhou o total vendido: 0
Bônus: 0
 Jose Ganhou o número de clientes: 0
Bônus: 0
```

A segunda linha está sempre sendo escrita com aquele espaço antes do nome, alguém pode me ajudar?

O código:

```
def EncontrarOrdem(self,maior,nome,valor,tipo):
    for i in range(0,4):
        if(maior[0] == valor[i] and
            maior[1] != valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.4
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' Ganhou o ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        elif(maior[0] == valor[i] and
            maior[1] == valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.7 / 2
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' Empatou com o segundo lugar no ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        if(maior[1] == valor[i] and
            maior[2] != valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.3
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' ficou em segundo(a) no ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        elif (maior[1] == valor[i] and
              maior[2] == valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.5 / 2
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' Empatou com o terceiro lugar no ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        if(maior[2] == valor[i] and
            maior[3] != valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.2
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' ficou em terceiro(a) no ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        elif (maior[2] == valor[i] and
              maior[3] == valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.3 / 2
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' Empatou com o quarto lugar no ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
        if(maior[3] == valor[i]):
            bonus = 1500 * 0.1
            return (bonus,nome[i] + ' ficou em último(a) no' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n')
```

Comment: As strings estão começando com uma variável, e terminando com um \n. E eu ja conferi as variáveis, elas não contém espaços no início, então só me resta pensar no \n, ele deixa algum lixo na memória? Obs: os dois valores de retorno são float e string, depois eu apenas imprimo a string ao chamar a função no código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente colocar no comando `print()` o argumento `sep=''`.
Ficaria algo assim:

```py
print(EncontrarOrdem(self,maior,nome,valor,tipo),sep='')
```

O separador padrão é um espaço. Ao colocar `''` (nada entre as aspas), talvez o espaço seja removido.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado. Vou pesquisar mais sobre esse argumento

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, suas strings possuem espaço no início e no fim. Por exemplo:
' carro '
Basta remover. Ficaria assim:
'carro'
Acredito ser esse o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Caso existam espaços em volta dos nomes, você poderia utilizar `nome[i].strip()` para removê-los. Também recomendaria utilizar o format ao invés de concatenar os valores com `+`,  deste modo você terá um controle maior da saída e não precisará fazer conversões para string, por exemplo:
`nome[i] + ' Ganhou o ' + tipo + ': ' + str(valor[i]) + '\n' + 'Bônus: ' + str(bonus) + '\n'`
poderia ser substituído por:
`f"{nome[i].strip()} Ganhou o {tipo}: {valor[i]}\nBônus: {bonus}\n"`

Comment: melhorou bastante o código, obrigado, mas o problema ainda persiste

Comment: Você poderia disponibilizar uma imagem dessa saída? Poderia também disponibilizar a chamada do print? Acredito que ficaria mais fácil. Um exemplo do vetor de nomes também seria útil.

Comment: valLiqui[i] = self.EncontrarOrdem(maiorLiqui,valNome,valLiqui,'total vendido') 


# Guardo todas as variáveis em um array, pois são dados de várias pessoas.
print(valLiqui[i]) # Imprimo elas na tela no mesmo array


o resultado vou editar na pergunta

Comment: Aqui os itens são impressos com uma quebra de linha. Ex.:
Pedro Ganhou o tipo total de vendas: 40<br/>
Bônus: 600.0<br/>
<br/>
Pedro Ganhou o tipo total de vendas: 40<br/>
Bônus: 600.0<br/>
Quebra de linha esta que não está aparecendo na sua saída. Você poderia tentar retirar todos os '\n' do fim dos returns para ver se eles são os causadores destes espaços.